# Improve soil in established flower garden

Tags: soil-amendment

The soil in my garden is very hard; it's probably clay if I do just a little deep. However, I already have some plants established in my garden and I don't want to dig them up. It's a small area, about 20  20 feet. Is there a way to make the soil better?

Comment: Where are you in the world and what type of plants do you have growing - shrubs? trees? perennials... please can you  clarify or add a photo

Comment: have you looked into top mulching with rotted wood chips because some plants love them, and others hate them. This will let the soil infiltrate, but not disturb the soil.

Comment: I came to ask this exact question, "glad" to see I am not the only one. @Bamboo I'm curious - how might the answer differ for each of these?  I my case, I have a mix of bulbs, perennials, and lavender.

Comment: @SethMMorton for that sort of mix, ,just spreading a layer of composted garden material or composted manure or other composted materials at least twice year will improve the soil over time. Where this doesn't work so well is if there's a lot of low groundcover plants which are likely to get buried, and woody based shrubs mean mulch should not be up against or in contact with the woody parts.